# What does the mut usage here?

Tags: rust

See the comments, What does the `mut self_encoded` means here?

```rs
pub trait DecodeLength {
    fn len(self_encoded: &[u8]) -> Result<usize, Error>;
}

// This can compile.
impl DecodeLength for i32 {
    // here
    fn len(mut self_encoded: &[u8]) -> Result<usize, Error> {
       usize::try_from(u32::from(Compact::<u32>::decode(&mut self_encoded)?))
            .map_err(|_| "Failed convert decoded size into usize.".into())
    }
}

//  This way not works since the signature of this len is not correctly.
// impl DecodeLength for i32 {
//     fn len(self_encoded: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, Error> {
//         Ok(2)
//     }
// }
```

Comment: The `mut` before `self_encoded` isn't needed. The commented code doesn't compile because it uses a `&mut` reference instead of `&`.

Comment: Thanks! I added more implementation details of the `len()` in the answer. What if I need a mutable reference in the function body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must remember when you change your `fn` like this

```
fn len(mut self_encoded: &[u8]) -> usize {
    2
}
```

you didn't change actual input, your input still is `&[u8]`, you just tell the compiler that value of input variable can be changed
like this

```
impl DecodeLength for i32 {
    // here
    fn len(mut self_encoded: &[u8]) -> usize {
        self_encoded = b"123";
        2
    }
}
```

but when you change the input type `&[u8]` to `&mut [u8]` you chose a new type for input

now compiler give you an error and says "expected `&[u8]` but found `&mut [u8]`

```
//  Error: expected fn pointer `fn(&[u8]) -> _` found fn pointer `fn(&mut [u8]) -> _
impl DecodeLength for i32 {
    fn len(self_encoded: &mut [u8]) -> usize {
        2
    }
}
```

remember `&[u8]` and `&mut [u8]` are different and have different use

## [Edit]

you can't use `?` in function when your function doesn't return `Result`

## [Edit 2]

look at the following code

```
impl DecodeLength for i32 {
    // here
    fn len(mut self_encoded: &[u8]) -> usize {
      let mut_ref = &mut self_encoded; // this give you `&mut &[u8]`
      let mut_ref2 = self_encoded.as_mut(); // Error: `as_mut` is only valid for `&mut` references
      1
    }
}
```

you can't change `&[u8]` type into `&mut [u8]`, this will give you an error

the simple way is change your `DecodeLength` like this

```
pub trait DecodeLength {
    fn len(self_encoded: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, Error>;
}
```

## `&[u8]`

it's reference to a bytes slice, value of this slice can't change and is immutable, you can only read it

```
fn immutable_slice(input: &[u8]) {
  //input[0] = b'a'; // Give you an Error
  if input[0] == b'a' {
    println!("Index 0 is 'a'");
  }
}
```

## `&mut [u8]`

it's reference to a editable bytes slice, it' can be change inside of fn

```
fn mutable_slice(input: &mut [u8]) {
  input[0] = b'a';
  println!("{:?}", input);
}
```

you can test it like this

```
fn main() {
  let numbers1: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  immutable_slice(&numbers1);
  let mut numbers2: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  mutable_slice(&mut numbers2);
}
```

Comment: If we leave aside the `DecodeLengthtrait`, are the `mut self_encoded: &[u8]` and `self_encoded: &mut [u8]` equivalent?

Comment: I update the code snippets, please update your answer edit part.

Comment: short answer is No,  `mut self_encoded: &[u8]` and `self_ecnode: &mut [u8]` are not same, and they are different

Comment: What's the difference between them? I don't know how to search about this. or Do you have any suggestions about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add example for difference between `&[u8]` and `&mut [u8]`